# Where and how to apply user permission and remove the config that makes any user able to access GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

At BigQuery, I need to set up some user permissions/roles to make them able to access only a few tables of my project.

Trying to do this, I realized that the current configuration allows any member of the organization (any user email with the company domain) to access GCP. I want to change it because i don't think this is the appropriate config, but I don't know how :(

And, with the user permissions, all Google documentation i find shows the config in some kind of code. I don't know where to apply that and have already tried roles at IAM, but it seems to not apply.

May anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

The [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#required_permissions) to grant users access to specific datasets are:

- bigquery.dataOwner
- bigquery.admin

This could be done through the UI:[image: Share Dataset]

To specifically control access to tables and views, you would need to specify the table(s)/View(s), through a similar [access policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#create) process.

Also through the UI: [image: Share table]